# Devise custom after resetting password not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:edit]

  def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    completed_reset_path
    #super(resource)
  end
```

routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: "users/passwords"}
match "completed_reset", to: 'home#completed_reset', via: [:get]
```

HomeController:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def completed_reset
  end
end
```

When I reset my password, I get redirected to root instead of to completed_reset_path . Why is this happening?

Comment: Just a hunch: Could you try "users/passwords/completed_reset" as the route?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
get 'completed_reset', :to => 'home#completed_reset'
```

Instead of:

```
match "completed_reset", to: 'home#completed_reset', via: [:get]
```

Comment: Why should that be any different?

Answer (score 0):

In config/initializers/devise.rb:
Set `config.sign_in_after_reset_password = false`